# Get menu item by name or slug

Tags: menus

I would like to retrieve a menu item object by name. I am not sure what method to use.

A similar method that works for menu names is [`wp_get_nav_menu_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_object/). If you read the documentation, you can pass the menu name and the menu object would be retrieved.

I would like to do the same thing, but for menu items instead of menus. I like to pass a menu item name or slug, and in return, I get the menu item object. Is there such method?

Thanks.

Comment: This will give you an array of items for a particular menu:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/